# JPA merging two or more tables into another table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to take some columns from some tables(entities) and store them to another table's columns with JPA, Hibernate?

For example;
Table1 : id, name,  surname, ...
Table2 : id, school, city, ...

Table3: unqId, name, surname, school, city

Select from Table1 and Table2 and insert into Table3.

Or alternatively, Select result as Table3 entity from Table1 and Table2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the `Table1` and `Table2` has some relation, or say are joinable. Then you can do a insert query in SQL like this,

```
insert into Table3 (....) select .... from Table1 inner join Table2..
```

Now, how would you achieve the same using JPA.

1. Get the desired POJO using a `NamedQuery` or whatever you think is better
2. Set the `Table3` properties using the result in hand
3. Persist `Table3`

In case `Table1` and `Table2` are not joinable, then you need to query both separately. And do the same steps, 2 and 3, in JPA. In SQL it would be possible to use stored-procedure for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have used the native SQL with first option.